# How do you print JSON from the mongdb ruby driver?

Tags: ruby, json, mongodb

When I do a find query from the mongodb JavaScript console, I get a beautiful JSON response. However, when I do a find with the ruby driver, it stores the JSON as some Ruby object. How do I convert this back to JSON? Or, better yet, how do I just get the JSON without doing the extra conversions?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Have you tried `.to_json`

Comment: @Jens - `to_json` would be extra conversion which Matt tries to avoid.

Comment: @Eimantas: The native format of mongo **isn't** JSON. It's BSON. So it must be converted no matter what.

Comment: True, but BSON seems so close to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. I was using ruby-1.9.1-p378 with rvm. I removed that. Now, I'm using the system ruby-1.8.7-p174 that came with the SnowLeopard install DVD. But, I was still getting an error with the to_json method except this time it was saying, stack level too deep. I did:

```
require 'json/pure'
```

instead of

```
require 'json'
```

Then, I changed the code to look something like this:
http://github.com/banker/mongulator/blob/master/mongulator.rb#L53

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
cursor = persons.find(
  {"loc" => {"$near" => [params[:lat].to_f, params[:lng].to_f]}},
  {:limit => 20})
content_type "application/json"
JSON.pretty_generate(cursor.to_a)
```

The complete file is here:
http://github.com/acani/acani-sinatra/blob/master/acani.rb

And, it worked, even with pretty json like the facebook graph api gives you. To return the JSON all on one line, just do something like:

```
  cursor.to_a.to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Code you get on the javascript console is also converted. It's not the native output of MongoDB, the Native format is [BSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON). To Get JSON on the javascript console it must be converted. In Ruby you should be able to do the same thing with the `.to_json` instance method of your Object.

Comment: I tried .to_json but I get an illegal instruction error without explanation. Maybe JSON doesn't work with BSON::OrderedHash, a subclass of Hash. Or maybe it's my version of Ruby 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

now you can do `cursor.find.to_a.inspect`